# SQL Query in PHPMyAdmin not Executing showing Error #1071

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to execute the following sql query. which giving `error #1071`. I've changed `'varchar (300)'` to `'varchar (255)'` and `'MyISAM'` to `'InnoDB'`. Still not working. I'm not familiar with MySQL.

Final Code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nwjhmu_users_oauth` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `identifier` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `displayName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `profileURL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `photoURL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `webSiteURL` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `age` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `birthDay` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `birthMonth` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `birthYear` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `registerDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `provider` (`provider`,`identifier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Instead of expecting us to know all error codes by number, could you provide the actual error text? That usually gives some nice hints about the problem :)

Comment: Works fine for me [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/079cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query. The syntax is perfectly fine. 
However, you are using 'provider' and 'identifier' as unique keys which might be very long according to the limitations on the key length in MySQL. However, it seems that you are using the outdated version MySQL because the current version supports key size of upto 3072 bytes.

One workaround can be that you can use (say) first 100 chars of the fields:

```
UNIQUE KEY `provider` (`provider`(100),`identifier`(100))
```

instead of:

```
UNIQUE KEY `provider` (`provider`,`identifier`)
```

Comment: Thanks Bhoot for your answer.